# ANTLR : A lexer or a parser error?

Tags: antlr, lexer

I wrote a simple lexer in ANTLR and the grammer for ID is something like this :

```
ID  :   (('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*|'_'('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*);
```

(No digits are allowed at the beginning)

when I generated the code (in java) and tested the input :

```
3a
```

I expected an error but the input was recognized as "INT ID" , how can i fix the grammer to make it report an error ?(with only lexer rules)

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your rule could be rewritten into:

```java
ID
 : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' |'_')*
 ;
```

or with `fragments` (rules that won't produce tokens, but are only used by other lexer rules):

```java
ID
 : (Letter | '_') (Letter| Digit |'_')*
 ;

fragment Letter
 : 'a'..'z'
 | 'A'..'Z'
 ;

fragment Digit
 : '0'..'9'
 ;
```

But if input like `"3a"` is recognized by your lexer and produces the tokens `INT` and `ID`, then you shouldn't change anything. A problem with such input would probably come up in your parser rule(s) because it is semantically incorrect.

If you really want to let the lexer handle this kind of stuff, you could do something like this:

```java
INT
 : Digit+ (Letter {/* throw an exception */})?
 ;
```

And if you want to allow `INT` literals to possibly end with a `f` or `L`, then you'd first have to inspect the contents of `Letter` and if it's not `"f"` or `"L"`, the you throw an exception.